# If variance is a decreasing sequence, does it imply that sequence converges to mean in probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1$,$X_2$$\dots$ be a sequence of random variables (not necessarily iid), such that each $\mathbb{E}$($X_n$) = $\mu$, and suppose Var($X_n$) is decreasing sequence with limit 0. Is it true that $X_n\to$ $\mu$ ?

- Var($X_n$) = $\mathbb{E}$($X^2_n$) - $\mathbb{E}$($X_n$)$\mathbb{E}$($X_n$) =  $\mathbb{E}$($X^2_n$) - $\mu^2$. Since $\mu$ is a constant; $\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\mathbb{E}$($X^2_n$) = $\mu^2$. However, after that, what should be done? Do I should go for R-mean convergence or are there easy ways? I am confused. I believe that that limit will prove that random variables are iid, however I am not sure how to show that formally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $V[X_n]=E[|X_n-\mu|^2]\to 0$ we have $L^2$-convergence to $\mu$. Since the measure space is finite, $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence. Therefore $E[|X_n-\mu|]\to 0$ and $X_n\to \mu$ in $L^1$. $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in probability (use Markov's inequality).

Comment: I can learn these terms but in general, I don't know measure theory since my course is intermediate probability. Is there a way to solve it without using it? I think it will be more work but for example, I could not say measure space is finite with full confidence.

Comment: @what_is_2d-game when we deal with probability, the measure space is always finite: precisely $P(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: Oh okey, I see it now.